# Javascript идентификаторы

Tags: javascript

Всегда избегал JavaScript так как очень плохо понимаю как в нем работают идентификаторы и любой успех приводил к громоздкому и нереальному к использованию коду (который в последствии не использовался), но новая задача вынудила меня попытаться разобраться по лучше.

Итак, у меня существует SVG график с точками в этом духе:

```html
<circle id="point1" cx="10%" cy="10%" r="4"></circle>
<circle id="point2" cx="15%" cy="15%" r="4"></circle>
<circle id="point3" cx="20%" cy="20%" r="4"></circle>
```

При наведении на эти точки должна выводиться подсказка, каждая точка имеет свою подсказку. Единственный известный мне способ вывода таких подсказок при наведении на элемент SVG это JavaScript, потому соответственно он. Все примеры в интернете выполняют эту задачу на ура, но распространяются только на один указанный идентификатор **point** что изменить мне так и не удалось.

Каким образом можно распространить действие одного кода на все точки с идентификатором point + его порядковый номер? Т.е. чтобы при наведении на любую точку с идентификатором **point** я мог придать блоку div видимость, содержимое и коодинаты связанные именно с этой точкой?

Пример кода наверное не имеет смысла, но оставлю.

```js
point.addEventListener("mouseover", showInfo);
point.addEventListener("mouseout", hideInfo);

function showInfo(evt) {
  Info.style.display = "block";
}

function hideInfo(evt) {
  Info.style.display = "none";
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Использованы [data-атрибуты](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes), в которых можно сохранить не только порядковый номер (как в моём примере).

```js
var chart = document.getElementById("chart");
var points = chart.getElementsByClassName("point");

for (let point of points) {
  let id = point.getAttribute("data-id");
  let x = point.getAttribute("cx");
  let y = point.getAttribute("cy");
  point.addEventListener("mouseover", () => {
    showInfo(id, x, y)
  });
  point.addEventListener("mouseout", () => {
    hideInfo(id, x, y)
  });
}

function showInfo(id, x, y) {
  console.log("OVER " + id + "\nx: " + x + "\ty: " + y);
}

function hideInfo(id, x, y) {
  console.log("OUT " + id + "\nx: " + x + "\ty: " + y);
}
```

```html
<svg height="500" width="500" id="chart">
  <circle class="point" data-id="0" cx="10%" cy="10%" r="4"></circle>
  <circle class="point" data-id="1" cx="15%" cy="15%" r="4"></circle>
  <circle class="point" data-id="2" cx="20%" cy="20%" r="4"></circle>
</svg>
```

Comment: Я стал на несколько шагов ближе к пониманию data- и идентификаторов ну или как минимум смог достичь предполагаемой задачи их используя, но у меня все еще присутствует чувство, будто я не разобрался в задаче а лишь смог построить выполняющий мою задачу код, потому у меня вопрос.

Comment: document.getElementById("mypopup").innerHTML = info[id];

В часности к info[id] (var info = [массив, но это не важно]), как я понял он олицетворяет сотрудничество идентификаторов с основным javascript кодом всегда, если в качестве задачи стоит работа с data-, я верно понял? Вопрос конечно с очевидным ответом, но я лучше получу очевидный ответ и разберусь, чем очевидное но ошибочное приму за истину и буду ломать дрова. Благодарю за ответ заранее.

Comment: Как я понял, вы связываете индексы элементов [массива](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Learn/JavaScript/First_steps/Arrays#%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%B8_%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2_%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0) с идентификаторами элементов на странице. В этом случае значение атрибута `data-id` просто совпало с возможными значениями индексов в массиве

Answer (score 1):

Для этой цели Вам лучше использовать классы, а не идентификаторы.

Так или иначе, из кода в вопросе можно сделать селектор вида `[id^="point"]` и по нему получить все элементы, у которых `id` начинается с `point`. В таком случае код будет выглядеть как-то так:

```js
var points = document.querySelectorAll("[id^=\"point\"]");
for (var point of points) {
  point.addEventListener("mouseover", showInfo);
  point.addEventListener("mouseout", hideInfo);
}

function showInfo(evt) {
  Info.style.display = "block";
}

function hideInfo(evt) {
  Info.style.display = "none";
}
```

В случае использования класса, например, `point`, код видоизменится следующим образом:

```js
var points = document.getElementsByClassName("point");
for (var point of points) {
  point.addEventListener("mouseover", showInfo);
  point.addEventListener("mouseout", hideInfo);
}

function showInfo(evt) {
  Info.style.display = "block";
}

function hideInfo(evt) {
  Info.style.display = "none";
}
```